# Merge two branches by using --ours for specific folder?

Tags: git

I have a repository that looks like this:

```
* Board A
| * Board B
| |
|/
*
```

The structure of both branches are the same:

```
.
├── bsp
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── ...
├── src
│   ├── a
│   └── b
├── Makefile
└── README.md
```

The bsp is differ in both branches.

If I do:

```
git checkout board-a
git merge board-b
```

I get with major difference between `bsp` folder, so I would like to have a merge but forcing   `ours` strategy in bsp folder, to keep it local to the current branch. Said differently I would like something like:

```
git checkout board-a
git merge board-b --ours=./bsp
```

Is it possible to do this in Git?

Of course I can `git difftool src/` and do the merge manually, but in this case it will not be a merge.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to start a normal merge, and then discard the changes in that directory before committing it:

```
git switch board-a
git merge --no-commit board-b
git restore --source=board-a bsp
git add bsp
# resolve any remaining conflicts
git commit
```

The `--no-commit` flag stops the merge before creating the commit, but leaves all the metadata in place to be read by `git commit`, as happens automatically if there are unresolved conflicts.